Failed to build envtools
I want to build envtools for my Ti chip.
And I use the command to build it, but I got error below.
#make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- envtools

scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
***
*** Configuration file ".config" not found!
***
*** Please run some configurator (e.g. "make oldconfig" or
*** "make menuconfig" or "make xconfig").
***
scripts/kconfig/Makefile:46: recipe for target 'syncconfig' failed
make[2]: *** [syncconfig] Error 1
Makefile:539: recipe for target 'syncconfig' failed
make[1]: *** [syncconfig] Error 2
make: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/uboot.release'.  Stop.

If someone can help to check anything lost?
Expect to build pass

Do you have a .config?  The error seems pretty clear.

What you need to do is right there in the output.
